# Checkout before stages in YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

Im doing a checkout in my stages to download the repo.

```
stages:
    - stage: dev    
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploySQLObjects
        displayName: "Deploy SQL objects" 
        environment: "Synapse_DEV"
        strategy:   
          runOnce:
            deploy:
             steps:   
              - checkout: self 
     - stage: test
         .......
     - stage: prod
         .......
```

Is it possible do to the checkout before all stages and let all stages use this checkout?
Im not quite sure how to do it. Ive only seen examples with steps without stages

Comment: You could use dependencies between stages and do the checkout in your first stage and make sure all other stages depend on it, however, that would mean all your steps that need this checkout must run on the same agent. I would not recommend to go this way because I foresee this would become quite a tricky situation.

A checkout is intended to checkout for all steps in your job that runs on an agent running this actual job.

Can you maybe describe why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure Hosted build agents, each job will use a new build instance. In this case, you can not use one checkout step...

If you are using Self Hosted build agents, you may add one checkout stage to some shareable folder through git commands and use it for other jobs.